# AsyncTaskLoader vs Asyncqueryhandler

Tags: android

Can anyone please tell me difference between  AsyncTaskLoader vs AsyncQueryHandler?

I want to use AsynTaskLoader in my app..  The existing one in my app is AsyncQueryHandler..

Am I right about that AsyncTaskLoader is the replacement of AsyncQueryHandler?

Correct me If I am wrong..  I am very new to android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the docs :

[`AsyncQueryHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) :

> A helper class to help make handling asynchronous ContentResolver queries easier.

[`AsyncTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) :

> Abstract Loader that provides an AsyncTask to do the work. See Loader and LoaderManager for more details.

So they are pretty different. `AsyncQueryHandler` is used for querying/inserting asynchronously into a `ContentResolver`, and the `AsyncTaskLoader` it is an implementation of the new [`Loader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) mechanism (introduced in API Level 11) which uses an `AsyncTask` do to any kind of background processing (HTTP, SQL, etc).

You should also look at [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), maybe it is what you need.

I would say that if you just want to read from a `ContentResolver` you should use a `CursorLoader`, but if you want to insert, delete etc. into that `ContentResolver`, maybe it is better to use the `AsyncQueryHandler`.

Comment: Really thanks for the reply...  So you meant that no need to use CursorLoader in the case I go with AsyncTaskLoader..  Isn't it?

Comment: yeah. use just one of them, which ever suits you best. on SO we +1 the answer if it was useful and can skip the 'thanks' part :)

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu what happens to the AsyncQueryHandler operations (CRUD)  if the activity that started them gets killed or paused? Do these operations continue to do their work or their killed/cancelled? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`CursorLoader` is a subclass of `AsyncTaskLoader`. And LoaderManager & CursorLoader only provide a way to access results of async invoked query() operations on ContentResolvers. Other ContentResolver operations are still synchronous.

However, `AsyncQueryHandler` invokes all ContentResolver calls asynchronously. Not just query, but also insert, delete, update.